# Performance Considerations for using SQL Server Extended Properties

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

To All,

We are wanting to use Extended Properties as part of our database documentation.  One of my co-workers mentioned that on a prior project they used Extended Properties and it impacted database performance.

I have been searching the internet for any corroborating information in regard to this.  I've not found anything.

Has anyone encountered this?  If so, is there an article or link where I can read up on this?

Thanks - Mr. Do

Note: this is a SQL Server 2005 database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your colegue is wrong. There is no performance impact on normal database operations if you use extended properties.

The only impact extendet properties have is on **operations that read or write extended properties**. This impact depends on the way properties are read and set, and the size and number of properties.

Answer (score 1):

They are simply text properties: not considered in plans, compiling, statistics, anything.

Unless you do some painful/fancy "SELECT * FROM [sys.extended_properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177541.aspx)" stuff...

They are also very useful to document and add comments to the database objects: especially in conjunction with 3rd party tools like [Red Gate SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm) (may be others)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've seen is that when I am updating them, I am sometimes affected by locks already on the object when particular processes are running, but performance is not a reason to avoid using them.

FYI: I noticed that extended properties disappear on UDFs when a UDF is altered to remove schemabinding and then re-add schemabinding.

Comment: Only on multi statement table valued funcs. In SQL 2000, permissions were lost too!